# Tridion not generating any logs on CD

Tags: content-delivery, 2013-sp1, logging

We are running SDL 2013 SP1 with Java 7 on the delivery side. We are trying to upgrade from an earlier release of DXA Java to DXA 1.4.1. While upgrading we noticed that none of Tridion CD libraries are generating any log information even though we have everything defined in the logback.xml file. Not having any log info makes troubleshooting impossible.

Below is the logback.xml we are using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<property name="log.pattern" value="%date %-5level %logger{0} - %message%n"/>
<property name="log.history" value="7"/>
<property name="log.folder" value="D:/Apache/tomcat-sh-web13/logs"/>
<property name="log.level" value="WARN"/>
<property name="log.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="rollingTransportLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/tridion/cd_transport.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
        <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <prudent>true</prudent>
</appender>
<appender name="rollingDeployerLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/tridion/cd_deployer.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
        <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <prudent>true</prudent>
</appender>
<appender name="rollingMonitorLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/tridion/cd_monitor.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
        <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <prudent>true</prudent>
</appender>
<appender name="rollingCoreLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/tridion/cd_core.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
        <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <prudent>true</prudent>
</appender>
<appender name="rollingSessionPreviewLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/tridion/cd_preview.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
        <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <prudent>true</prudent>
</appender>
<appender name="rollingHibernateLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/tridion/cd_hibernate.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>
<encoder>
        <charset>${log.encoding}</charset>
    <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
</encoder>
<prudent>true</prudent>
</appender>  


<!-- Loggers -->
<logger name="com.tridion" level="${log.level}"/>
<logger name="com.tridion.transport">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingTransportLog"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.tridion.transport.HTTPSReceiverServlet">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.tridion.transport.transportpackage">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.tridion.transformer">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.tridion.deployer">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.tridion.tcdl">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.tridion.event">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingDeployerLog"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.tridion.monitor">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingMonitorLog"/>
</logger>
<logger name="Tridion.ContentDelivery" level="${log.level}">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingCoreLog"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.tridion.preview">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingSessionPreviewLog"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.tridion.storage.persistence.session">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingSessionPreviewLog"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingHibernateLog"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.hibernate.type">
    <appender-ref ref="rollingHibernateLog"/>
</logger>

<root level="OFF">
    <!-- <level value="${log.level}" /> -->
    <appender-ref ref="rollingCoreLog"/>
</root>

<logger name="org.springframework"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.web"/>
<logger name="org.dd4t"/>
<logger name="com.sdl.webapp"/>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT:**

I noticed that Tomcat is not picking up the `logback.xml` from my `web-inf/classes` folder and instead it is taking a `logback.xml` from `Tomcat/lib`. I found that `tomcat-juli.jar` was replaced to use logback's version of `tomcat-juli.jar` and `Tomcat/lib` folder contained `tomcat-juli-adapters.jar`. After removing `tomcat-juli-adapters.jar` and replacing `tomcat-juli.jar` with the original one and deleting `logback.xml` from `Tomcat/lib` now even the blank files defined in my `logback.xml` are not being created.

Comment: I also noticed <configuration> tag is not closed?

Comment: It is actually closed in the xml file. Somehow got removed when copy/pasting the config here.

Comment: Does the user under which you are running the windows service have access to the log location?

Comment: @Hiren The service is running under "Local System Account" which has full access to the log location. If files are being created I doubt this is a permissions issue.

Comment: You can rule out a permission problem by using Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx); any file system related problems would be highlighted.   Have you tried manually setting the <root level> logging to any other value than off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did some research and found that Apache `Apache ActiveMQ` causes a conflict because it has a dependency on `slf4j-log4j` and thus logback is not initialized properly (**multiple slf4j bindings**). We were able to get the CD logging working after removing `activemq-all.jar` and instead using only the required jar files.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set this value:

```
<property name="log.level" value="WARN"/>
```

to DEBUG

```
<property name="log.level" value="DEBUG"/>
```

And restart the deployer service.

Comment: Setting log.level to DEBUG made no difference at all. All Tridion log files are created in the specified location but they are all blank.

Comment: If you restart tomcat and Tridion services, the creation date of the log files changes acording to the restart time?

Comment: Yes the creation date does change. In fact if I delete all log files from the specified folder and restart tomcat service, I can see new log files being created. But all blank.

Comment: You could try with the reference logback.xml sample file, wich comes with the installation CD of tridion 2013sp1 (Content Delivery\roles\context\configuration\samples) changing only the log folder route. Just to ensure there are no errors in your logback.xml

Comment: Already tried the sample logback file from 2013sp1 installation CD. Didn't work either.

Comment: It's very strange. Try checking folder permissions (change to grant write permission to everyone). Also you colud try to uninstall Java and install other version, also updating your jars  in the deployer bin folder. If this doesnt work, you should contact Tridion support. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried the solution, but maybe the problem is in the 4 `logger` elements, that must be before de `root` node. Have you tried changing this?

As the problem seems to be lying in the logback configuration, the console of the application must be showing some traces of the loading of the logback configuration. Have you seen the console logs?

Comment: This is running under Tomcat which is run as a Windows Service in our case. Console shows same basic info as in STDOUT file which is not very informative.

Answer (score 0):

Check on the permission of the D:/Apache/tomcat-sh-web13/logs folder. It's possible there's no write permission